# Adding properties to ActiveRecord enum field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `User` model in my Rails 4 app. It contains enum for account_type

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum account_type: [manager: 0, contractor: 1, employee: 2]
end
```

At the moment `account_type` is used to modify behavior of several actions. But in the future I will need to introduce several properties which will have different values for different account types (e.g. rate limits on some API endpoints or subscription price).

How should I handle this?

I can add new model `UserAccountType` model and set `belongs_to`-`has_many` association link between it and `User` model, but I will lose access to methods like `manager?` which are conveniently provided by `ActiveRecord`. Also I will have to seed related table appropriately which means that I will have to place mapping 'account type' <--> integer in `seeds.rb` and make sure that it creates records for all account types which is nor DRY. Is there a way to do this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a simple role system. the Rolify gem is great for that: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify. It's also easy to add additional convenience methods on top of what's included.

Enough people have tried to solve this problem that some patterns have appeared. For example, are you sure for the life of your project a single role per user will suffice? You may want an array type(or one to many) instead of an enum.

If you want to implement it yourself, if you are using Postgres the array field type might be a good approach for storing and adding "roles". As for the convenience methods, you could replace something like is_manager? in a few lines. I wouldn't let that deter you from creating a more fitting and sustainable data model.

example:

```
def is_manager?
  User.find(1).roles.include?('manager')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you mention that you wish to add extra attributes to `enum` objects -- you have to be careful to understand what you want to add.

As per the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

> Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name.

Basically, this means that the stored value for your `enum` attribute will be a number; Rails will "translate" that number into its verbose form. Can easily be achieved with a single instance method if you wanted.

The use case you've given us is therefore not valid:

> Note that when an array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, :active is mapped to 0 as it's the first element, and :archived is mapped to 1. In general, the i-th element is mapped to i-1 in the database.
>
> `Conversation.statuses[:active]    # => 0`
>
> `Conversation.statuses["archived"] # => 1`

--

The difference with your question is that if you wanted to add *more* specification to the `enum` functionality, you're really getting into the realm of another model.

As mentioned by `@errata`, if you wanted to use your example, you'd be better with role-based functionality.

One of the best things you pick up from working on larger projects is the need to be specific about functionality. It's easy to say "I need a new model", very different to understand what it has to do on a functional level.

Therefore, what I would recommend is looking at what you're trying to achieve *exactly*. If you want "extra" attributes etc, you'll need another model. If you're just using single values, stick with an `enum`.

---

> rate limits on some API endpoints or subscription price

I'd personally use something like the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :account_type
   delegate :rate_limit, to: :account_type #-> @user.rate_limit.speed
end 

#app/models/account_type.rb
class AccountType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   belongs_to :rate_limit #-> maybe
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find x
@user.rate_limit.throttle
```

Could probably use something more flexible, but the above should be okay.

Comment: I understand what I want to achieve in the end, I just lack rails experience. For example I didn't know about `delegate` before and it really looks like it may save me from a lot of typing when using my models. Thanks

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction (terms to google)? How should database be seeded with account types? Rate limits are connected with roles so `AccountType` has to have `role` integer field.